# Is it possible to redirect stdout as stdin to same program?

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, stdin, io-redirection

I am writing a filter, and I am exploring an approach to write the program. I was wondering if this is possible: from input in stdin, write to stdout, but redirect this stdout such that the program reads the generated stdout as if it were stdin, again, thus re-processing the data. I do not wish to store the data in a gigantic array -- I wish to do this using streams, solely. Is this even possible? (if not, that's fine too.) Also, a note: I wish to do this only in a single source file of C code.

Comment: It's very possible, but how to do it depends very much on what system you're on (e.g. Windows or POSIX (like Linux, OSX))?

Comment: Sorry, I just added a note: I want to do this only using code. I believe this is possible by piping on Unix command line, but I want to do this using pure C.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Windows has enough of a POSIX interface to do this, no?

Comment: @Potatoswatter Mostly, but still somewhat incompatible (especially its [`_pipe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edze9h7e.aspx) function).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that a pipe's size is limited.

Comment: You can replace your current stdin with your stdout. But it sounds like you rather want to consume the entire existing stdin, and then re-process the output you create ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a [pipe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pipe.html) to yourself in any POSIX system.

But ["There ain't no such thing as a free lunch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch). If you need to store data, it has to go somewhere. The pipe is backed by a buffer managed by the OS.

You can literally set the ends of the pipe to back `stdin` and `stdout` (as in Joachim's answer), but I'd advise against that, as it would override the usual input and output channels of the program. (Neither C nor any POSIX service will "tee" the stream so the user can see it as well as have it echoed inside the program.)

Answer (score 1):

Create a [pipe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html). [Duplicate](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) the read-end of the pipe as the new `STDIN_FILENO`, the write-end as `STDOUT_FILENO`, and you're all set. Everything you now write to `stdout` will be available on `stdin`.